# Consulta con UNION en JPQL lanza error

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, eclipselink

estoy tratando de realizar una consulta mediante JPA, utilizando como implementación EclipseLink 2.6.2, y me está lanzando un error pero no consigo ver que esta mal en la consulta, la he simplificado al máximo para poder abstraer el error, sé que se podría realizar con nativeQuery pero en la consulta completa utilizo un constructor de una clase para encapsular el resultado, por eso me gustaría hacerlo utilizando JPQL y quiero evitar nativeQuery.

```
String query = "select vl.producto,vl.neto ,vl.cantidad "
                    + " from VentaLinea  vl "
                    + " union "
                    + " select fel.producto ,fel.neto ,fel.cantidad  "
                    + " from FacturaEmitidaLinea fel   ";

resultado = em.createQuery(query)
                .setFirstResult(0)
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .getResultList();
```

Según el [apartado dedicado a UNION de eclipselink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/j_union.htm) esta consulta debería funcionar pero está lanzando el siguiente error:

> Internal Exception:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION (SELECT
>   t2.ID, t2.barCode, t2.BASE, t2.BORRADOR, t2.CREATED_BY, t2.CREATIO' at
>   line 1 Error Code: 1064

Y la traza completa del error:

> Internal Exception:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION (SELECT
>   t2.ID, t2.barCode, t2.BASE, t2.BORRADOR, t2.CREATED_BY, t2.CREATIO' at
>   line 1 Error Code: 1064 Call: (*consulta)(org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:684)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2740)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllReportQueryRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2677)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ReportQuery.java:852)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:460)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
>     ... 225 more Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION (SELECT
>   t2.ID, t2.barCode, t2.BASE, t2.BORRADOR, t2.CREATED_BY, t2.CREATIO' at
>   line 1    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:941)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2470)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2617)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2550)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1009)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:644)
>     ... 244 more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tras darle mil vueltas al asunto he descubierto que se trata de un bug en la implementación de EclipseLink, cuando esta trabaja con MySql >=5.6.

Este bug lleva abierto varios años y parece que nadie se ha interesado mucho así que no creo que lo vallan a solucionar en un futuro cercano, aunque espero equivocarme. Finalmente he tenido que trabajar con nativeQuery.

Dejo el enlace por si alguien mas se topa con el y quiere votarlo.
[UNION not working in Mysql 5.6](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378573)
Un saludo